# My function keeps giving NaN

Tags: javascript

I have made a function but it keeps returning NaN. I can't figure it out why it does this.

```js
function voeruit(){
 var invoer1 = 2000;
 var invoer2 = 11000;
 var invoer3 = 5;
 var datum = new Date();
 var jaar = datum.getFullYear();
 berekenen(invoer1, invoer2, invoer3, jaar);
}


function berekenen(invoer1, invoer2, invoer3, jaar) 
 {
  var leeftijd = jaar - invoer1;

  var daling1 = invoer3 / 100;
  var daling = 1 - daling;

  var totdaling = Math.pow(daling, leeftijd);
  var waarde = invoer2 * totdaling;

  var uitkomst = waarde;
  window.alert(uitkomst);
 }
```

it's a summary where, i think is the problem, so there might be a syntax error.
It's an other language than english, because i'm dutch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a bug here:

```
var daling = 1 - daling;
```

Which should be:

```
var daling = 1 - daling1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo

```
var daling1 = invoer3 / 100;
var daling = 1 - daling;  //<-- daling1?
```

Presumably that should be

```
var daling1 = invoer3 / 100;
var daling = 1 - daling1;
```

Otherwise you're setting daling to 1 - undefined. Which is indeed not a number.

Answer (score 0):

To able to return something from function you should use

```
return someValue;
```

But in your code i could not find something like this. How can you expect function return **the value** if you dont write **return** statement?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `var daling = 1 - daling;` and `daling` not defined yet, may be you should use `daling1`

And also I want to suggest to not use variable names which like each other they are always confusing.